# Moving a point along an ellipse given initial point $P$ and arc-length $d$

Tags: plane-curves, arc-length

Fix a reference frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose you have an ellipse $\mathcal{E}$, a point $P \in \mathcal{E}$ and a real number $d$, where it is implicitly understood that $d>0$ means movement along a counter-clockwise direction ($d<0$ clockwise).

The problem is: find a function which, given in input ($P$, $d$, $\mathcal{E}$), gives, as output, a new point, $Q$, such that: $Q \in \mathcal{E}$ and the (signed) arc-length between $P$ and $Q$ is $d$ (the direction is implicitly specified by the sign of $d$).

**In short**: find the point $Q$ obtained by moving a point $P$ of "distance" $d$ along an ellipse.

---

It may be that this problem has no closed-form solution (I suspect it due to the fact that the arc-length of an ellipse has no closed-form), in which case useful approximations can be discussed.

Comment: Please refer my answer of another question [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093569/points-on-an-ellipse/2093586#2093586).

Comment: In your answer, you have written "for a small eccentricity $e$". Does the formula for $\theta(t)$ applies only for small $e$ ? I need to work with generic eccentricity, since I have (in different cases) high values of $e$, $e=0.5$ and also very small $e$.